# Changing FontSize relationally to the windowsize with WPF?

Tags: wpf, window, font-size

Is it possible, that the FontSize getting smaller if I shrink the window and getting bigger if I enlarge the window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap your text inside a `Viewbox`.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="Sizes to fit!"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Comment: Now its gettings smaller if i shrink the window but FontSize="16" haven't any effect. From default, the font is very big.

Comment: Yes, of course. If you wish to impose limits, play with the `StretchDirection` property of `Viewbox`.

Comment: @CannibalSmith 1 upvote as I was facing the same issue and Stretch and viewbox did the magic.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried this, but I imagine you can bind the font size property of your text to the window size through a converter method.  I wouldn't try to bind directly, as that way madness lies.

The other option would be to handle the window resize events and send the font size to each control manually...

--edit--
Just searched Google and found [this result](http://jeffmclean.net/blog/?p=8), which may be what you want.

Comment: Unhappily the converter was written in C#. But I'm programming with Visual Basic and I've problems to rewrite it in vb. But I think it isn't very difficult to program an own converter.