# Auto-size text on button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, layout

I have a window with few buttons.

The buttons are auto-sized, in order to fill all avaible space. It works.

BUT size of the text on these buttons is fixed.

I want to make this text as large, as possible.

How to achieve this?

Comment: See: [Changing FontSize relationally to the windowsize with WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071949/changing-fontsize-relationally-to-the-windowsize-with-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, Wrap the content inside a ViewBox

```
<Button Name="button" Content="Hello" Height="100" Width="200" >
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock>MyButton</TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```